# How to stop the book module defaulting to IE7 standards mode?

Tags: nodes

I currently have a problem whereby when visiting a page created with the book module it forces IE into IE7 standards document mode.

I am running Drupal 7 with the Omega 3 base theme.  I have disabled the RDF module and added:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

Which forces all other areas of the site to render correctly, just not in the book module pages.

Has anyone else come across this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may have visited the book page in IE, and selected compatibility mode once, and it is now being remembered.  Another possibility is that you have an internet zone rule (probably an intranet rule) that is forcing compatibility mode on.  Your IT department may be forcing this via a policy, too.

I have had some problems with just using the meta in the header of a page, and have been using this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_html_head_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
  // disable IE compatability mode
  // see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

  $head_elements['x_ua_compatible'] = array(
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'name' => 'X-UA-Compatible',
      'content' => 'IE=Edge,chrome=1',
    ),
  );

  $head_elements['x_ua_compatible']['#attached']['drupal_add_http_header'][] = 
    array('X-UA-Compatible', $head_elements['x_ua_compatible']['#attributes']['content']);
}
```

This adds the meta, so you can see it when you do a view source, and it also adds a proper HTTP header to disable it.

Just note that if this is being enforced via policy or IE settings, you may not be able to override it.

Comment: Hi, I tried this, however it doesn't seem to set the document mode on any part of the site, however if I manually put the HTML meta into the html.tpl.php template file it works - apart from on the book module.

Comment: @inertiahz Not sure why that doesn't work.  I have it live on a few sites, and see the HTTP header in the response.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that because I have access to the server the site runs on I could add the custom header X-UA-Compatible - IE=edge.  This has solved the issue server side.  I haven't found a solution if you don't have access to the server.

Comment: FWIW, you don't need server access to do this.  You can normally add this to the .htaccess for the site, too, unless your server admin has diabled Header in .htaccess.

Comment: Ah yes, good call - unfortunately I'm stuck using IIS6 so forgot about htaccess.